# Problema al actualizar datos en pantalla mediante AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, thymeleaf

Tengo este enlace , que lo que hace mediante AJAX es dar un "me gusta" a la respuesta de un usuario.
Donde pone `${respuesta.likes}` muestro los likes de la respuesta.
La petición me la hace correctamente, es decir , me suma los "me gusta" a la respuesta, pero el problema esta en que no me cambia los "me gusta" que muestro por pantalla en `${respuesta.likes}`.

```
<span th:text="${respuesta.likes}"></span>
<a id="like" class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-lg colorIcono" th:href="${'/respuesta/like/' + respuesta.respuestaSuya.id + '/' + respuesta.id}"></a>
```

Aqui dejo el método AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $("#like").click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(event.target).attr("href"),
            type: "GET",
              beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
              },
              success: function(data) {                
                  console.log("ok");
              }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Y el controlador que ejecuta la acción

```
@GetMapping(value = "/respuesta/like/{id}/{idRes}")
    public String darLike(@PathVariable("id")Long id,@PathVariable("idRes")Long idRes){
        Usuario user  = repoUsuario.usuarioPorId(id);
        Respuesta res = repoRespuesta.respuestaPorId(idRes);
        user.setPuntos(user.getPuntos() + 1);
        res.setPuntos(res.getPuntos() + 1);
        res.setLikes(res.getLikes() + 1);
        repoUsuario.save(user);
        repoRespuesta.save(res);
        return "redirect:/respuesta/respuesta/" + res.getPostRespuesta().getId();
        }
```

Comment: En este bloque: `success: function(data) {                
                  console.log("ok");
              }` tienes que leer `data`, extraer la información que te manda el  servidor y actualizar ahí la información del span.

Comment: Pero cuando muestro `data` me devuelve toda la página en html, como podría acceder a la información necesaria ? @A.Cedano

Comment: Desde el código del servidor debes devolver **unicamente un JSON válido**, y en el `success` buscar el valor en ese JSON. Supongamos que devuelves algo como esto desde el servidor: `{
 "id": 1
}` en la variable `data` del `success`, encontrarás el valor `1` haciendo esto: `data.id`.